# Dystopian future, illegal parents are punished by rapid aging

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

Please help me identify a book/story I read some years ago.

Dystopian SF future. World is extremely overpopulated and food scarce. People have gradually moved into megacities each consisting of just a single giant building covering 100's square km to free as much country as possible for food production. Pregnancies are controlled and need to be approved, people who conceive illegal child are sentenced to slow death in several years by accelerated aging.

The main character is a member of police team performing raids against illegal parents injecting them with the aging substance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This reminds me of *[Futu.re](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1771617)* (or *Будущее*) a novel by Dmitry Glukhovsky, first published (in Russian) in 2013. It is set in Europe in the 25th century after the invention of a drug which stops the aging process, rendering the population essentially immortal. As a result, conceiving a baby without a license is strictly forbidden, and if it is discovered the parents are injected with  an "aging virus", which makes them grow old at an accelerated rate.

The main character is Jan Nachtigal, one of the stormtroopers resposible for enforcing the population control rules, and fighting against the terrorist "Life Party". As in the original question, the population live in giant, multi-kilometre tall, skyscapers, to free up as much land as possible for food production. Several user reviews are available at [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/27300577-futu-re).

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is correct! I forgot about the immortality, that of course worsens the overpopulation concerns.